# Localizing OAuth messages in Web Api

Tags: .net, oauth, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I configured my Web.Api project to use OAuth authentication mechanisms with this options :

```
...
   OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
...
```

so it handles my authentication process completely through a url like : `http://mysite/token`

if I pass a wrong combination of username/password, it gives me the following json response (with `Status Code:400 Bad Request`) :

```
{"error":"invalid_grant",
 "error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}
```

I want to know  :
1- Is there any way to localize this message?
2- Is there any way to add a custom header to its response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should override GrantResourceOwnerCredentials function. In that function you can add headers or set error text if it is necessary.

```
    Public Overrides Function GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context As OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext) As Task 
    .............
     context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Challenge", {result.Challenge})
     context.SetError("invalid challenge response")
  ..............
     End Function
```

Comment: in you implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Comment: oh my god! why didn't see that class! :) sometimes thinking too complex close our eyes on simple visible things!...anyway thanks!